# How to check username and password in access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have followed some tutorials on youtube and come up with the following code. My goal is to allow a user to manage other users once they are logged in to the program.

```
private void txtBoxLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Docket\Database1.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;");
        string cmdText = "select * from login where Username=" + "? and [Password]=?";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText,connection);
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtboxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtBoxPassword.Text);
            int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
                else
                MessageBox.Show("Fail");
        }                                
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is the login credentials always fails even though I have some dummy credentials added to the database. Otherwise I can access and open the database and/or read/write info to it.

Comment: Try `select count(*)` instead. `ExecuteScalar` returns the first value in the first row of the results. You're getting whatever's in that first row/column of the login table, presumably a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` 
will execute the query and return one row to the `result` here your query is

```
select * from login where Username=" + "? and [Password]=?"
```

so if any row exist in the table with the given details it will return that row and try to assign in `result`.

So you need to check  whether any row exist in the table with the given username and password and return number of rows exist. so use

```
select count(*) from login where Username=" + "? and [Password]=?"
```

and do

```
int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Now `result` will have `0` if no row exist with given details else it will return `number of rows` exist with given values

```
**Please try to save password in encrypted format 
instead of plain text for security reasons
```

Comment: This did the trick, I wasn't checking for the username/password correctly. I'll work on the encryption part as well.